Add enclosed quotes for CSV file using groovy
I have below input CSV file.
0123,00001,00001,01,4.00,T,H,xds,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1234,00001,00001,,TI,2024,,4956.00,0.00,,,,,
1234,00001,00001,,TI,2024,,4956.00,0.00,,,,,1234

Using below groovy script I am able to add enclosed quotes but it's adding an additional line starting with enclosed quotes.
   def Message processData(Message message) {
// Retrieve the body of the message as a string (assuming the CSV is in the message body)
def body = message.getBody(String)

// Split the body into lines
def lines = body.split('\n')

// Enclose each field in double quotes
def quotedLines = lines.collect { line ->
    line.split(',').collect { field ->
        "\"${field}\""
    }.join(',')
}

// Join the quoted lines back together
def result = quotedLines.join('\n')

// Set the modified body back to the message
message.setBody(result)

return message

}
Below is the output with above groovy code
"0123","00001","00001","01","4.00","T","H","xds","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","
 "
 "1234","00001","00001","","TI","2024","","4956.00","0.00","","","","","
 "
 "1234","00001","00001","","TI","2024","","4956.00","0.00","","","","","1234"

Expected output should be like below.
 "0123","00001","00001","01","4.00","T","H","xds","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
 "1234","00001","00001","","TI","2024","","4956.00","0.00","","","","","
 "1234","00001","00001","","TI","2024","","4956.00","0.00","","","","","1234"

could you please help me with this.
Regards,
Janardhan

Count the fields in the input and the output. The 'extra' line is in fact the last field in each row. You're splitting the file on \n, but I suspect that your line terminator is \r\n, so the \r is being used as the last field on the line and wrapped in quotes. Try splitting on \r\n. But...

...this is valid CSV. You should only need to wrap text field if there's an embedded comma. Why are you doing this at all?

Most likely is your input using DOS/Windows line-breaks; so splitting
with just \n keeps the \r in there and therefor you will see
line-breaks inside your last cell.
Since you are already eagerly modifying the whole CSV, you can do that
also in one (two) sweeps with regexp:
data.replaceAll(/(?m)(^|$)/, '"').replaceAll(/,/, '","')

Word of warning: not using proper parsers/libraries (e.g. RFC 4180
conform) for reading or writing CSV sets you up for problems down the
road.  Here you have something, that can not work with perfectly valid
CSV and you are "fixing" it by banging strings together.  You are making
a bad situation worse.
